# Is there a word for making one's self better by looking at other people's worse problem?

Tags: single-word-requests

**Schadenfreude** is not the word I'm looking for.

Here's some context, I lost $1000 from a scam in cryptocurrency yesterday, but to cope up, I just tell myself, "It's a huge amount of money for me, but hey there are people who lost way more money, people who lost their life savings. It's only $1000."

Comment: Please show how you would like to use this word.

Comment: It's "minimizing", but I don't think there's a specific term for this type of minimization.

Comment: You cope up?? Never heard that use of cope.  Sounds like relativizing to me.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake on that `cope up` part. I googled it, it seems it should be `cope with`. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-eminent candidate is ***consolation***, with its adjective ***consolatory***

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consolation)
> consolation:
> something that makes someone who is sad or disappointed feel better:
> $ *If it's (of) any consolation (to you), you're not the only one he was nasty to.*
> *I didn't know what to say - I just offered a few words of consolation*

$ The second Cambridge example above is relevant to the circumstances in your question - it is consolation resulting from considering another's similar or worse circumstances.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consolatory)
> consolatory:
> making or intended to make someone who is sad or disappointed feel better